# How can I mechanically secure a headphone cable after soldering on a new connector?

Tags: connector, soldering, cables, repair, headphones

My headphone (Sennheiser HD 265) has a socketed connection between cable and headphone. The headphone cable had come loose, so I bought a new connector and soldered the headphone cable to it.

The connector looks like this:

[image: Sennheiser headphone connector]

Now, the soldering worked fine. However, I don't know how to mechanically secure the cable to the connector. I initially tried just soldering it and letting it leave the connector via the small plastic "tube" (strain relief) on the left side, but it turned out that the cable will be pulled and, worse, twisted when the headphone is in use, which causes it to come loose.

How can I secure the cable against pulling/twisting?

I tried:

- squeezing the "tube" part of the connector so it holds the cable
- putting sticky tape across cable and connector

but that was not sufficient.

Comment: Just glue it in?

Comment: @PlasmaHH: That looks like an answer :-). Maybe you could clarify a bit - what glue, and between which parts?

Comment: For glue I would use 2-component epoxy glue and fill everything with that. It will be a challenge to do that neatly. This glue can be bought almost anywhere. But why not just buy a complete cable + connectors assembly? I have seen these being sold on eBay. It is difficult to get this type of connector to the same state as a factory made cable assembly.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie: I wanted to save money :-). A complete cable costs 35 - 40 € (it's a proprietary Sennheiser connector), while a connector only costs a few Euros.

Answer (score 3):

I find that cyanoacrylate glue (Krazy Glue, Super Glue) works well for securing cables in strain releifs,

Ideally I push the cable into the plug too far, glue the bit that sticks in and then pull it back to the correct location.

Comment: I tend to find that cyanoacrylate gets too brittle to work properly with soft materials, but maybe it's just the brand/type that I'm using.

Comment: some people use it end-glue rubber strips to make o-rings and belts. it seems to work too well on skin.

Answer (score 2):

You could try a cable tie fairly tight around the entry, but if that doesn't work, there are malleable silicone compounds (sometimes called "mouldable glue") that set into flexible rubber.  [Sugru](https://sugru.com) is one such.

Comment: This answer will get half as useful once the link to "this stuff" vanishes

Comment: it's been there the last five years - if they go out of business I guess it won't be useful at all. I'll edit though. Thanks.

Comment: also note that "sugru" is a well-known substance in some parts of the world, but totally unknown in others, so if you could point out the important properties for this application ("is a kind of putty that gets solid when exposed to pink alligators") in the answer, that'd be cool – I've never touched that suff.

Comment: it's very useful by the way!

Comment: @dmb: there are other similar products

Comment: possibly, this is just the one I am aware of.

Comment: Sounds awesome, never heard of it. I'll keep this in mind, even if I don't use it for the cable.